# Calling a named template from an imported .xsl file explicitely

Tags: xslt, import, xslt-2.0, saxon

**I have the following situation:**
I am using a 3rd party xsl template system ([kosit XRechnung](https://github.com/itplr-kosit/validator-configuration-xrechnung)), which allows to configure custom adaptions via specification of your own .xsl files as processing entry points.

Here's the process:

```
+--------+                                         
|        |                                         
|        |                                         
|        |                                         
| in.xml |                                         
|        |                                         
+--------+                                         
    |                                              
    |                                              
    |                                              
    V                                              
+--------+                                         
|        |                                         
|        |  import   +--------+                    
| my.xsl | <-------- |        |                    
|        |           | adapt  |  import +---------+
|        |           |  .xsl  | <-------|         |
+--------+           |        |         | default |
    |                |        |         |  .xsl   |
   -|                +--------+         |         |
    |                                   |         |
    V                                   +---------+
+--------+                                         
|        |                                         
|        |                                         
|   out  |                                         
|  .xml  |                                         
|        |                                         
+--------+
```

`my.xsl` is the processing entry point fed with some .xml data, which is provided by me
`adapt.xsl`is an adaption which provides a named template called at some point by
`default.xsl` which does a lot of stuff to create the final output XML document.

**default.xsl:**

```
<!-- ... -->
        <xsl:when test="s:scenario">
          <rep:scenarioMatched>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="s:scenario" mode="copy" />
            <xsl:call-template name="documentData" />
            <xsl:sequence select="$validationStepResults" />
          </rep:scenarioMatched>
        </xsl:when>
<!-- ... -->
```

**adapt.xsl:**

```
<!-- Overwritten (default.xsl) -->
<xsl:template name="documentData">
    <rep:documentData>
        <xsl:for-each select="
            $input-document/*/cac:AccountingSupplierParty/cac:Party/cac:PartyLegalEntity/cbc:RegistrationName, 
            $input-document/rsm:CrossIndustryInvoice/rsm:SupplyChainTradeTransaction/ram:ApplicableHeaderTradeAgreement/ram:SellerTradeParty/ram:Name">
            <seller>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </seller>
        </xsl:for-each>
        
        <xsl:for-each select="
            $input-document/*/cbc:ID,
            $input-document/rsm:CrossIndustryInvoice/rsm:ExchangedDocument/ram:ID">
            <id>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </id>
        </xsl:for-each>
        
        <xsl:for-each select="$input-document/*/cbc:IssueDate,
            $input-document/rsm:CrossIndustryInvoice/rsm:ExchangedDocument/ram:IssueDateTime/udt:DateTimeString">
            <issueDate>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </issueDate>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </rep:documentData>
</xsl:template>
```

Now in my top level .xsl I can again override the named template which is called in the `default.xsl`:

**my.xsl:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:rep="http://www.xoev.de/de/validator/varl/1"
    xmlns:s="http://www.xoev.de/de/validator/framework/1/scenarios" 
    xmlns:in="http://www.xoev.de/de/validator/framework/1/createreportinput"
    xmlns:svrl="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/svrl"
    xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ubl="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
    xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" 
    xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2"
    xmlns:rsm="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:CrossIndustryInvoice:100"
    xmlns:ram="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:ReusableAggregateBusinessInformationEntity:100"
    xmlns:udt="urn:un:unece:uncefact:data:standard:UnqualifiedDataType:100"
    xmlns:myns="urn:mycompany:xrechnung:data:enhancements"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:import href="./adapt.xsl"/>

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Overwritten (default.xsl) -->
    <xsl:template name="documentData">
        <rep:documentData>
            <myns:MyContainer>
                <myns:MyElement>
                   <!-- Enhanced stuff -->
                </myns:MyElement>
            </myns:MyContainer>
            <!-- xsl:call-template name="documentData"/-->
        </rep:documentData>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The question is:

**How to apply the stuff defined in `adapt.xsl` without copying that xsl code for the `documentData` named template (without changing `default.xsl` or `adapt.xsl`)?**

Comment: I'm not sure that I correctly understood your question, but to avoid name clashes you can use namespaces. Maybe [this link](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-tipimpinc/index.html) does help.

Comment: @zx485 Well, I am not that well versed in XSLT obviously. _"you can use namespaces"_ How so without changing neither `default.xsl`, nor `adapt.xsl`?

Comment: The steps would be: 1) Create a namespace with `xslns:some="http:///..."` ") Use it in `adapt.xslt` to change it to `<xsl:template name="some:documentData">` 3) Call that in `my.xslt` with `<xsl:call-template name="some:documentData">`. You have to repeat the namespace decl in `my.xslt`.

Comment: @zx485 I have updated my question with the full content of `my.xsl`, if you would be so kind and explain the steps I need to do there, creating another namespace won't be a problem.

Comment: @zx485 Well, as mentioned: I don't want / can't change `adapt.xsl`. But ty for your efforts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222036/discussion-between---and-zx485).

Answer (score 1):

In the context of XSLT 3 packages this is possible, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#refer-to-overridden:

> Within a named template appearing as a child of xsl:override, the name
> `xsl:original` may appear as the value of the name attribute of
> xsl:call-template: for example, `<xsl:call-template name="xsl:original"/>`.

Saxon 9.8 and later support XSLT 3 with packages.

For the concrete example I think you would need to use a fourth file (e.g. `adapt-package-wrapper.xsl`) that is a named package importing `adapt.xsl` e.g.

```
<xsl:package xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0"
    name="http://example.com/adapt1" package-version="1.0">
    
    <xsl:expose component="template" names="documentData" visibility="public"/>
    
    <xsl:import href="adapt.xsl"/>
    
</xsl:package>
```

Then in `my.xsl` you would need to declare the override:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0">
    
    <xsl:use-package name="http://example.com/adapt1" version="1.0">
        <xsl:override>
          <xsl:template name="documentData">
            <rep:documentData>
              <myns:MyContainer>
                <myns:MyElement>
                   <!-- Enhanced stuff -->
                </myns:MyElement>
              </myns:MyContainer>
              <!-- xsl:call-template name="documentData"/-->
              <xsl:call-template name="xsl:original"/>
             </rep:documentData>
          </xsl:template>
        </xsl:override>
    </xsl:use-package>
    
    ...

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The main issue then is letting Saxon know how to map the package name `http://example.com/adapt1` to a package file, on the command line you would use e.g. `-lib:adapt-package-wrapper.xsl`. Or you can use a configuration file. Not sure whether you can do that in your environment.

Comment: Good to know. I am using the latest stable saxon release. I'll try that tomorrow. Ty so far.